# How can I get Header Response using HTTP Proxy Recording from Gatling

Tags: performance, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I need to correlate a couple of values, those value are sent on "Header Response" from the server. When I recorder my script using Gatling I'm able to record only the "Body Response no "Header Response".  I couldnt find this value on the "body response" because those values are on the "Header Response". Someone can help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve response headers in gatling and execute http call multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57584369/how-to-retrieve-response-headers-in-gatling-and-execute-http-call-multiple-times)

Comment: No It does not. I need to get Header Response from the HTTP Proxy recorder, Similar to the option "Body Response". You can check this option on the HTTP Proxy recorder (UI to recorder) and then you get reponse.html, but its only for body response, no for Header Response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, that's not possible with the recorder (contributions welcome).
You can check the response headers if you run your test and enable debug logging in logback.xml.

Comment: Thank you Stéphane LANDELLE! Yeah I can use other proxy to record the response from server like Fiddler. We can think on that Contribution!